# What does Euler equation mean?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In order to prove the Bernoulli’s principle ($\frac{p}{\rho} + \frac{1}{2}u^2+\phi = constant$ ), I have to use the [Euler equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29): $\frac{Du}{Dt} = -\frac{1}{\rho}\nabla p + g$.

I know how to prove it, but I didn't understand what does it mean and say (Euler equation)?

please explain me.

any help appreciated!

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you want to know? Can you maybe clarify a bit?

Comment: Have you looked at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)?

Comment: thank you both.. sorry for my english.. I give an example: Pythagorean theorem (a^2+b^2=c^2) means that in a right triangle, a^2+b^2=c^2 where: c represents the length of the hypotenuse, and a and b represent the lengths of the other two sides. thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euler equation is the special case of the Navier-Stokes equation that describes fluid motion. Euler equation stands for inviscid flow, i.e. flow with zero viscosity.

To get it a bit more explicit please visit
[wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_%28fluid_dynamics%29), and for further reference I would suggest you to search for some lecture notes online and select those you would like the most. This is quite popular topic, so there should not be any problem. As a suggestion you may want to have a look [here](http://www.jpoffline.com/mphys_y4.php).